# Nativescript & iOS DeviceCheck API

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

My team has a nativescript-vue application that is targeting the iOS platform.  We were trying  to uniquely identify the iOS device uuid via nativescript-uuid, but that appears to no longer supported. What is the best approach to use the DeviceCheck API?

Comment: May I know why do you think it's not supported anymore. I think it still works.

Comment: I was having difficulty getting the UUID from the plugin, I had an error message about a password.  Research into that led to this:  https://medium.com/walkin/how-to-uniquely-identify-an-ios-device-8bbd292737f7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right [nativescript-uuid](https://github.com/gdtdpt/nativescript-uuid) plugin is not updated to work with iOS 11 or later (DeviceCheck API).

An alternative could be using [nativescript-secure-storage](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-secure-storage) plugin, store the UUID you get using `UIDevice.currentDevice.identifierForVendor.UUIDString` for the first time, then it should return the same value even after reinstalling the app.

Comment: UIDevice.currentDevice.identifierForVendor.UUIDString did the trick, I am able to get the device UUID, so now I should be able to verify that against the DeviceCheck API